# How to use the where clause in generic definition correctly?

Tags: c#

I have the following code snippet:

```
public interface ITypeInterface { }

public interface IType1Things<T> where T : ITypeInterface
{
}

public interface IType2Things<T> where T : ITypeInterface
{
}

public interface ICommonInterface<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITypeInterface
    where T2 : ITypeInterface
    , IType1Things<T1>
    , IType2Things<T2>
{
}

public class Implementation<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITypeInterface
    where T2 : ITypeInterface
    , ICommonInterface<T1, T2>
{
}
```

The compiler complains that

> The type 'T2' cannot be used as type parameter 'T2' in the generic type or method 'ICommonInterface<T1, T2>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T2' to 'ClassLibrary1.IType1Things'.

I have no intention to convert T2 into IType1Things.
I just want to explain that T1 and T2 are both implementing the interface 'ITypeInterface'. How is the correct writing?

Comment: In `ICommonInterface`, did you want to constrain `T1` to `IType1Things<T1>` and `T2` to `IType2Things<T2>`? What you have written does not actually do that.

Comment: Or perhaps you want `ICommonInterface` to *inherit* `IType1Things<T1>` and `IType2Things<T2>`?

Comment: Yes, this is my intention. I want the inheritance of these two interfaces in the common. How can I express that correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that what you are saying in `ICommonInterface`'s declaration is that `T1` should implement `ITypeInterface`, and `T2` should implement all three of

- `ITypeInterface`
- `IType1Things<T1>`
- `IType2Things<T2>`

This causes the error at `Implementation`, because `ICommonInterface` requires `T2` to implement all those interfaces, but the `T2` you passed as a type argument (the `T2` in `Implementation`), only implements `ITypeInterface` and `ICommonInterface`.

But you meant to say that `IType1Things<T1>` and `IType2Things<T2>` are the superinterfaces of `ICommonInterface`.

The superinterfaces of an interface are written *before* the type constraints, prefixed with `:`. You can write:

```
public interface ICommonInterface<T1, T2>
    // these are the super interfaces of ICommonInterface
    : IType1Things<T1>
    , IType2Things<T2>

    // these are the type constraints for T1 and T2
    where T1 : ITypeInterface
    where T2 : ITypeInterface
{
}

public class Implementation<T1, T2>
    // judging from the context, ICommonInterface should be an interface of Implementation<T1, T2>, instead of a constraint of T2
    : ICommonInterface<T1, T2>
    where T1 : ITypeInterface
    where T2 : ITypeInterface
{
}
```

See also the syntax of [interface declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#182-interface-declarations) and [class declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#152-class-declarations).